# Styles on some of my pages don't work (although the pages are identical)

Tags: html, css

I just noticed that on some of my pages the .css file doesn't seem to...work? I know it sounds weird. But here's an example:

https://www.thecheers.org/The-Orbit/article_3020_Creationists-Celebrate-as-The-Lord-God-Privatises-Education.html

And now see this:
http://www.thecheers.org/Entertainment/article_3098_10-Indisputable-Facts-God-Exists.html

As you can see, on the first page styles don't even seem to exist.

I've been struggling with it for hours now, the reason being - all the articles run through the exact same page, so there shouldn't be any differences between the two pages. Just for the sake of trying, for a moment I did comment out the metatags, the footer, and even the entire article area, but the problem is still the same. And just to say once more - everything is presented to the user through the exact same file(s), so...why should styles work on one page and not the other.

Any ideas?

Comment: For starters, look at the console of the browser (`F12` or right mouse click and `Inspect` or `CTRL+SHIFT+I`) - there are lots of errors. First one is about CSS: `This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first link starts with `https://` while the second one starts with `http://`

Changing `https://` to `http://` of the first link solves your problem of CSS files that could not been loaded, but you should also look into other errors in browser console and solve them, too.

Comment: Argh, thank you. Now I feel like the person the IT support is asking for the have you turned in off and on again question from! Never even looked at that. Seems that for some reason Google has added https to some of the articles on my sites (clicked the link from google), not sure why...hmm. 

Thanks again! Never noticed that myself.

Comment: You are welcome, please click `accept` my answer if you feel it is the correct one.